# Call update method when a checkbox is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am trying to figure out how to call the update method when the user checks on the check box.  I want to update the database by deleting the value for the check box that is stored in the database.  Here is my code

```
<% @items.each do |item|%>
    <%if item.email == @user.email%>
        <%= form_for @item do |f| %>
            <%= f.check_box :to_do, url: update,:value => item.id%>
            <%= item.to_do%><br />
        <% end %>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31095692/1297435.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like..
 by using `checked` property..call ajax using jquery

```
$('input[type=checkbox][id=to_do]').change(function() {
         var hall_id = $('#to_do:checked').val();
         $.ajax({
         url:"/todo",
         type:'POST',
         //pass any agruments if needed
         //data: {"id": pass any data that you need},
         beforeSend: function (){
                //show the user that something is in progess
                 $("#to_do").parent().html("Submitting..");
                 },
         success:function(data){
         //update user on success/failure
         $("#to_do").parent().html("Submitted");
         }
         });

     })
```

**Now,just implement your action on the controller...thats it.**

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Do you mind going into more detail?  I am new to Ajax calls using Jquery

Comment: Ajax are asynchronous calls to server without a page refresh..just like you click like button on facebook and you get updated likes..without page refresh...thats ajax.....Go through this short tutorial..its good .. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp